# Data Binding of Computed Properties in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework

I am trying to find an effective way to databind computed fields of an Entity Framework model in winforms.  I am using Visual Studio 2008 and .NET framework 3.5.  An example would be for EntityX, say I have columnA and columnB, and I want a computed property named sumAB.  The way I have been doing this has been with partial classes:

```
public partial class EntityX 
{
    public int sumAB 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.columnA + this.columnB;
        }
    }
}
```

I then am using visual studio to add EntityX as a data source, so I can use the automatic drag and drop data binding.  The issue that I am having is that the computed properties are not appearing under the Data Source fields.  I am looking for a way to have the automatic databinding of computed fields.

I know I could do this manually, but then I would have to also manually write all of the binding code to refresh the field when columnA or columnB are changed.  I also do not have access to make this field computed on the SQL server side either.

Does anyone know of any ways to accomplish this or any other similar directions to persue?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I tested this on another machine, using Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4, and I am still receiving the same behavior.  Interestingly, I can manually create a textbox and add a databinding, and it will work fine, as below:

```
sumABTextBox.DataBindings.Add(
  new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", EntityXBindingSource, "sumAB", true));
```

It also worked if I placed the property in the .edmx file, but this is not desirable, as it will be wiped any time the database is updated.

Any other ideas?

**UPDATE 2**

Still no solution... I had to use alternatives in my code to meet deadlines.  I am still very interested in this if anyone finds an answer...

Comment: I can't see a reason why what you're doing wouldn't work. It's just a property, so how the code that's generating the datasource perceives it to be different is beyond me. Can you drill into the datasource xml in your solution and see whether the property bindings exist in there?

Comment: I took a look.  I am not familiar with the structure of these files, but I did notice that it has the automatically generated file listed, but it does not have my file listed as one of the CSVs in the TypeInfo tag.  I tried adding my file, saving, recompiling, but no luck...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds strange to me. Because I use the same approach in my project (Entity Framework, Self Tracking Entities, WCF, Winforms).

I constructed a simple winforms applciation to test it and the "computed" property just shows up in the databindings.Text property of a textbox control.

I created a simple class:

```
public partial class Test
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }

    public Test()
    {
    }
}
public partial class Test
{
    public int AB
    {
        get { return A * B; }
    }
}
```

Added a bindingsource to a form (with datasource pointing to an object of type Test) and three textboxes binded to the bindingsource and the properties: A, B and AB. In the constructor of the form I created an instance of test, populated values for A and B, set bindingsource.DataSource to the created instance and thinks were groovy on the form ;)

This simple test case would be no different from your situation, other than that you work with entities which are off-course just Objects. I really can't see the problem from your description...Any further comments could help me help you further...

Comment: Are the partial classes of EntityX in the same assembly? Else they would be compiled in two separate "full classes"...

Comment: I just tested with your sample, and it worked fine.  They are in the same assembly and namespace as far as I know.  The entity that I am using is auto-generated from the existing database, so I am not sure if this affects anything.  I have no trouble accessing these properties from the code, but the Data Source mapper is just ignoring them for some reason.

Comment: Are you connecting to the EF "directly" fromout a winForms application? Or do you expose services (WCF) and transport the entities? In the last case when you don't share the assembly that holds the entities but "know" the entities clientside by proxy generation it might be the case that your computed property isn't decorated with the [DataMember] attribute...so the winforms / clientside won't know this property.

Comment: Thanks for the continued help.  The EF entity is created directly in the winforms application, no WCF.  I tried adding the [DataMember] attribute just in case, but still no luck...

Comment: Can you sent me the sources? Some way...? Because now I WANT to know what's going on...

Answer (score 1):

I basically just asked the same question (WPF not WinForms) yesterday - [Show Computed Property in Entity Framework and WPF UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423580/show-computed-property-in-entity-framework-and-wpf-ui) .

In short, I couldn't find any automatic support.  I had to create the columns in my DataGridView for each computed property.  Then, to let the DataGridView know that those properties have updated, I have to call OnPropertyChanged("ComputedPropertyName") in the OnChanged partial method.

e.g.

```
public partial class Test
{
    public int AB
    {
        get { return A * B; }
    }

    public partial void OnAChanged()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("AB");
    }
    public partial void OnBChanged()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("AB");
    }
}
```

If there is an automatic way for this to work, I would like to know too.

Comment: Yep... thats essentially what I did as well... it doesn't make since that there wouldn't be an automatic way of doing this...

Comment: Glad that basically worked, are you accepting an answer on this question?